# Disable two mutually exclusive Sections when SectionGroup unchecked?

Tags: installation, nsis

I have an NSIS installer script with two SectionGroups. Each SectionGroup has two Sections, which are mutually exclusive.

I need to have the user able to uncheck the SectionGroup, which unchecks and disables ("grays-out") the Sections. Basically the user can choose to install one of the Sections, or none. On top of that, the second SectionGroup must be disabled if the first SectionGroup is unchecked.

I'm using this script as reference to control the mutually exclusive Sections: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Mutually_Exclusive_Sections

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your disable/gray requirement does not make sense. If you click the section group again to enable the "child sections", which of the two gets checked? And you would only be able to get out of the disabled state by clicking the group itself so I did not implement it.

In general, anything beyond simple radio button behavior gets complicated quickly. If you are using the 3.0 alpha version of NSIS then .onSelChange will actually tell you which item that changed which would make this less complicated...

```
Page Components "" SaveState
Page Instfiles


!include sections.nsh
!include logiclib.nsh

SectionGroup /e "Grp1" GRP_1
Section "A" SEC_A
SectionEnd
Section /o "B" SEC_B
SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

SectionGroup /e "Grp2" GRP_2
Section /o "C" SEC_C
SectionEnd
Section "D" SEC_D
SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

; Remove comments for a different behavior

Function SaveState
!macro SaveSel id var
SectionGetFlags ${id} ${var}
IntOp ${var} ${var} & ${SF_SELECTED}
!macroend
#SectionGetFlags ${GRP_1} $R0
!insertmacro SaveSel ${SEC_A} $R1
!insertmacro SaveSel ${SEC_B} $R2
#SectionGetFlags ${GRP_2} $R3
!insertmacro SaveSel ${SEC_C} $R4
!insertmacro SaveSel ${SEC_D} $R5
FunctionEnd

Function .onSelChange
!macro OneOfTwoItemsInAGroup gid gv i1 v1 i2 v2
#SectionGetFlags ${gid} $0
!insertmacro SaveSel ${i1} $1
!insertmacro SaveSel ${i2} $2
${If} $1 <> 0
${AndIf} $2 <> 0
    StrCpy $1 ${i1}
    ${IfThen} ${v1} = 0 ${|} StrCpy $1 ${i2} ${|}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection $1
    /*${If} ${gv} = $0 
        !insertmacro UnselectSection ${gid}
    ${EndIf}*/
${EndIf}
!macroend
!insertmacro OneOfTwoItemsInAGroup ${GRP_1} $R0 ${SEC_A} $R1 ${SEC_B} $R2
!insertmacro OneOfTwoItemsInAGroup ${GRP_2} $R3 ${SEC_C} $R4 ${SEC_D} $R5
Call SaveState
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am using 3.0. I'm just not explaining myself very accurately:

Grp1 and Grp2 are two optional categories in my installer (2 of 5, actually). A,B,C,D are files associated with their parent category.

Example:
-If Grp1 is checked by the user, A OR B can be installed.
-If Grp1 is NOT checked by the user, neither A NOR B can be installed.

In addition, Grp2 is dependent on Grp1:
-If Grp1 is checked and thus A OR B selected
    Then the user may check Grp2 to select C or D
-If Grp1 is not checked, none of the child sections can be installed.

I hope that's clearer.